# Displaying results in array with condition into a table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I am trying to display results in array according to row and col. I have tried the code below but 2 result is showing on next row I want it to be same row but different column.

Here is my code

```
<table id="TimeTable">
      <thead>
      <th style="width:20px; padding-right:10px;">No.</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Monday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Tuesday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Wednesday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Thursday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Friday</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $row):

                for($r=1; $r<=8; $r++) {

                    if ($row->row == $r) {
        ?>
            <tr>

            <td style="text-align: center; padding-right: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><strong><?php echo $r; ?>.</strong></td>

            <?php for($c=1; $c<=5; $c++) { ?>

                <td><?php 

                    if(($row->col == $c)) {
                        echo $row->subject." <br />Classroom: ".$row->classroom." <br />Time: ".$row->time; 
                    } 

                ?></td>

                     <?php  } //col for loop ?>


            </tr>

        <?php       } //if  
                } // row for loop 
         endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: Here is the table what i am getting]

If `row = 1` it should be in same row now its creating 5.

Your suggestion and help is much appreciated.

Comment: can i see the value of `$rows`?

Comment: Hello, I change the position of foreach loop to inside td and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for any trouble I able to solve it here is the correction

```
<table id="TimeTable">
      <thead>
      <th style="width:20px; padding-right:10px;">No.</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Monday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Tuesday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Wednesday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Thursday</th>
      <th style="width:160px; padding-right:10px;">Friday</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php for($r=1; $r<=8; $r++) {  ?>
            <tr>

            <td style="text-align: center; padding-right: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><strong><?php echo $r; ?>.</strong></td>

            <?php for($c=1; $c<=5; $c++) { ?>

                <td><?php 
                    foreach ($rows as $row):
                        if(($row->row == $r) && ($row->col == $c)) {
                            echo $row->subject." <br />Classroom: ".$row->classroom." <br />Time: ".$row->time; 
                        } 
                    endforeach;
                ?></td>

                     <?php  } //col for loop ?>

            </tr>

        <?php    
                } // row for loop 
          ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```